# iOS Phonegap push notification shows but no sound or badge

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a iOS app using PushPlugin for push notifications. So far almost everything works. I can receive the push notification on the device but no sound plays (when on sound) and it doesnt vibrate (when set to vibrate) also no badge appears. Is this something with the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes? I read something saying you need to register for the use of sounds, and badges. this is on iOS 8 using phonegap 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Some [people were reporting this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/434), but only for iOS 7 (so far as I know). I was able to get badge to work using a fork mentioned in that issue, but not sound (yet). It's possible your issue is different, but you might choose to try forking this and giving it a try anyway...

https://github.com/raix/PushPlugin/commits/fix-ios7-badge